# Are my calculations correct?

Tags: experimental-chemistry

The highlighted portions are my calculations. I am unsure whether i am going in the right direction or my sig figs are off. Am I supposed to use only 3 sig figs or what the calculator shows?

volume delivered=(final volume from trial 1) – (initial volume from trial 1)

7.50 mL – 0.00 mL = 7.50 mL

mass water=(mass beaker + water) – (mass of empty beaker)

29.691 mL – 22.109 mL = 7.582 g

density water  (mass water from trial 1) / (volume delivered from trial 1)

7.582 g / 7.50 mL = 1.01093 g/mL

average density= (density 1) + (density 2) + (density 3) + (density 4)/ 4

1.011 g/mL + 1.003 g/mL + 0.999 g/mL + 1.002 g/mL / 4 = 1.004 g/mL

% error= |theoretical value - experimental value| / theoretical value x 100

percent error = 0.997324 - 1.004/ 0.997324 = -0.00468 * 100 = -0.47%

[image]

Comment: This is not formatted in a way where people are going to be able to help.

Comment: additional details have been added

Comment: Question titles should be like book titles. They distinguish the book from other books, give a hint about the content, but do not tell the full story. The content then should elaborate the topic to full depth the author is able to do.

Answer (score 6):

Oscar has already explained that your calculations are fine. I see a serious practical problem though. I guess this is a lab experiment for teaching the concept of calibrating a pipette.

I am not aware of any typical 10 mL graduated pipette which can read volumes like 0.03 mL. Are you sure it is a pipet not a (micro)buret? How did someone read 0.03 mL as the initial reading on a pipet? How can one deliver 7.48 mL or 7.51 mL?

Proper calibration work of glassware in classical analytical chemistry requires buoyancy corrections.

Simple rule, don't worry about significant figures until the end. Your balance can read up to 3 decimal places. The calibrated volume by this hypothetical pipet can also be reported to 3 decimal places.

Comment: Those numbers were given to me. I did not perform any measurements.

Comment: Okay, then it is just "made-up" numbers from someone's mind.

Comment: Our professor provided the data that is not highlighted.

Comment: No problem. He just made up numbers during Corona times. In reality no pipet can deliver 7.48 or 7.51 mL. Consider it is an exercise.

Comment: @M. Farooq: I think what they meant is a burette, not a pippette.

Comment: @MathewMahindaratne, This is what I suspected. Even if it is a buret, the procedure is poorly executed. Most likely the instructor never performed any real calibrations.

Answer (score 3):

They look right to me except for the percent error calculation.  You should render

Precent error = (Measured - theoreticel)/(theoretical) ×100%

Here that would be positive, but you have a negative number so it looks like you turned the formula around.